# Wrench rotating and translating in space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

An astronaut throws a wrench in space, in a such way that the wrench rotates and translates.

Will the wrench stop rotating if no external force acts upon it?

Comment: Conservation of angular and linear momentum dictates that the wrench will continue to rotate and translate until it has transferred its angular and linear momentum to another body by a collision with one or more bodies.  If you want more commentary on this question you can post another question.  The question as currently asked has two problems, 1) the way you asked it requires only a yes or no answer, and 2) to give a deeper answer requires justifying "Why" Newton's first law works - which is not a question that conventional physics can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the wrench will continue to rotate, as angular momentum is conserved in the absence of external forces.

Comment: "..angular momentum is conserved in the absence of external forces **or torques**".

Comment: How do we justify this according to Newton laws?

Comment: A torque is just a force at a distance. Newton's laws play into the conservation of angular momentum in this way.